# Precomposing monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monads, composition, monad-transformers

Suppose I have two monad transformers

```
T1 :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
T2 :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

with instances

```
instance MonadTrans T1
instance MonadTrans T2
```

and some

```
X :: (((* -> *) -> * -> *) -> ((* -> *) -> * -> *) -> * -> *)
```

such as

```
newtype X t1 t2 a b = X { x :: t1 (t2 a) b }
```

for which I would like to define something along the lines

```
instance (MonadTrans t1, MonadTrans t2) => MonadTrans (X t1 t2) where
    lift = X . lift . lift
```

so that I can use `lift` to lift `m a` into `X T1 T2 m a`?

The problem here seems to be that the `lift`s act on some monad `Monad m => m a` which I cannot guarantee to be produce in the intermediate steps. But this is confusing for me. I am providing an implementation of `lift` so I can assume I have `Monad m => m a`, so I apply the rightmost `lift` and get `T1 m a` that I know nothing about, but shouldn't it be implied that `T1 m` is a `Monad`? If not why cannot I simply add this to the constraint of my instance

```
instance ( MonadTrans t1
         , MonadTrans t2
         , Monad (t2 m) ) => MonadTrans (X t1 t2) where ...
```

This does not work either. I have an intuition that by the above I am saying "should there be `t1`, `t2`, `m` such that ..." which is too weak to prove that `X t1 t2` is a transformer (works for any/all `Monad m`). But it still doesn't make much sense to me, can a valid monad transformer produce a non-monad when applied to a monad? If not, I should be able to get away with the instance of `MonadTrans (X t1 t2)`.

Is there a trick to do it that just eludes me or is there a reason why it cannot be done (theoretical or a limitation of what current compilers support).

Would the implication correspond to anything other than

```
instance (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => Monad (t m) where
    return  = lift . return
    a >>= b = ... # no sensible generic implementation
```

which would overlap other instances / could not provide the specific bind? Couldn't this be worked around with some indirection? Making `returnT :: Monad m => a -> t m a` and `bindT :: Monad m => t m a -> (a -> t m b) -> t m b` part of `MonadTrans` so that one can then write

```
instance MonadTrans (StateT s) where
    lift = ...
    returnT = ...
    bindT = ...

...

instance (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => Monad (t m) where
    return  = returnT
    a >>= b = a `bindT` b
```

This kind of instances is not currently valid due to overlapping, would they however be feasible, useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [C]an a valid monad transformer produce a non-monad when applied to a monad?

No. A monad transformer is a type constructor `t :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *)` which takes a monad as an argument and produces a new monad.

While I'd like to see it more explicitly stated, [the `transformers` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html) does say "A monad transformer makes a new monad out of an existing monad", and it's implied by [the `MonadTrans` laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t:MonadTrans):

```
lift . return = return
lift (m >>= f) = lift m >>= (lift . f)
```

Obviously these laws only make sense if `lift m` is indeed a monadic computation. As you pointed out in the comments, all bets are off if we have non-lawful instances to contend with. This is Haskell, not Idris, so we're used to asking politely for laws to be satisfied using documentation, rather than requiring it by force using types.

A more "modern" `MonadTrans` might require explicit proof that `t m` is a monad whenever `m` is. Here I'm using [the "entailment" operator `:-`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t::-45-) from [Kmett's `constraints` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) to say that `Monad m` implies `Monad (t m)`:

```
class MonadTrans t where
    transform :: Monad m :- Monad (t m)
    lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

(This is more or less the same idea that @MigMit developed in his answer, but using off-the-shelf components.)

Why doesn't the `MonadTrans` in `transformers` feature the `transform` member? When it was written GHC didn't support the `:-` operator (the `ConstraintKinds` extension hadn't been invented). There's lots and lots of code in the world which depends on the `MonadTrans` without `transform`, so we can't really go back and add it in without [a really good reason](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal), and in practice the `transform` method doesn't really buy you much.

Comment: Thank you! Any chance of ever being added?

Comment: @jd823592 I doubt it. It'd break too much code - every `MonadTrans` instance in the world, including those in third-party closed-source codebases, would have to be changed to implement the `transform` member, which is not always trivial - and in practice `transform` doesn't really turn out to be all that useful so the benefits don't outweigh the costs. (I've updated my answer.)

Comment: But since no code really uses the feature cant there be default definition of `transform` which would fail. Since it is not being used it wouldn't break code, and transformers used to break stuff from one version to next, that's what versioning is good for :) so even then, no `transform` for transformers :'( :)? Of course standard transformers would get proper implementation.

Comment: @jd823592 As soon as you try to do something interesting with `transform`, eg, [talking about monad transformer stacks as first class citizens](https://gist.github.com/benjamin-hodgson/dad9ba2292aed0f0724ae9526f8a00f1), you need every transformer you're interested in to have a working `transform`, not just the ones in `transformers`. If some transformer `MyT` has `transform = undefined` then I can't use `ReaderT r :.: MyT` as a transformer because `lift` and `>>=` will blow up. (`transform` contains actual useful runtime data, namely (a way to get) an implementation of `>>=` and `return`.)

Comment: I don't see how `lift` depends on `transform`, especially as in current code it doesn't

Comment: @jd823592 [I need it to tell the elaborator where to dispatch the calls to `lift`.](https://gist.github.com/benjamin-hodgson/dad9ba2292aed0f0724ae9526f8a00f1#file-transformerstacks-hs-L37-L39)

Comment: But `transform` is being used only in context that wasn't possible with transformers-0.5 so why should it blow up for all code? Sorry I am dumb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135637/discussion-between-benjamin-hodgson-and-jd823592).

Answer (score 3):

First of all: what you want is impossible. You've correctly identified the problem: even if `m` is a monad, and `t` — a transformer, nobody guarantees that `t m` would be a monad.

On the other hand, it usually is. But — at least theoretically — not always, so, you'd have to somehow mark the occasions when it is. Which means marking it with an instance of another typeclass that you'd have to define yourself. Let's see how it works.

We'll start with a name for our new class:

```
class MonadTrans t => MonadTransComposeable t where
```

Now, `where` what? We want to generate a `Monad (t m)` instance. Unfortunately, it's not something we can do. Class instances, while being just data, are not considered the same kind of data as everything else; we can't make a function that generates them. So, we have to work around this somehow. But if we have such a thing, then the class is pretty simple

```
class MonadTrans t => MonadTransComposeable t where
    transformedInstance :: Monad m => MonadInstance (t m)
```

Let's define `MonadInstance` now. We want to make sure that if there is `MonadInstance n`, then `n` is a monad. `GADT`s come to the rescue:

```
data MonadInstance n where MonadInstance :: Monad n => MonadInstance n
```

Notice that the `MonadInstance` constructor has a context, which guarantees that we can't make `MonadInstance n` without `n` being a `Monad`.

We can define instances of `MonadTransComposeable` now:

```
instance MonadTransComposeable (StateT s) where
    transformedInstance = MonadInstance
```

It would work, since it's already established in the `transformers` package that whenever `m` is a monad, `StateT m` is a monad too. Therefore, `MonadInstance` constructor makes sense.

Now we can compose `MonadTrans` and `MonadTransComposeable`. Using your own definition

```
newtype X t1 (t2 :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *)) m a = X { x :: t1 (t2 m) a }
```

we can define an instance. We now can prove that `t2 m` is a monad; it's not automatic, and we have to tell Haskell which `transformedInstance` to use, but it's not hard:

```
instance (MonadTrans t1, MonadTransComposeable t2) => MonadTrans (X t1 t2) where
  lift :: forall m a. (Monad m) => m a -> X t1 t2 m a
  lift ma =
    case transformedInstance :: MonadInstance (t2 m) of
      MonadInstance -> X (lift (lift ma))
```

---

Now, let's do something fun. Let's tell Haskell, that whenever `t1` and `t2` are "good" (composeable) monad transformers, `X t1 t2` is too.

As before, it's quite easy:

```
instance (MonadTransComposeable t1, MonadTransComposeable t2) => MonadTransComposeable (X t1 t2) where
  transformedInstance = MonadInstance
```

Same as with `StateT`. The catch is that now Haskell would complain that it can't know if `X t1 t2 m` is really a monad. Which is fair — we didn't define an instance. Let's do that.

We will use the fact that `t1 (t2 m)` is a monad. So, we make this explicit:

```
transformedInstance2 :: forall t1 t2 m. (MonadTransComposeable t1, MonadTransComposeable t2, Monad m) => MonadInstance (t1 (t2 m))
transformedInstance2 =
  case transformedInstance :: MonadInstance (t2 m) of
    MonadInstance -> transformedInstance
```

Now, we'll define a `Monad (X t1 t2 m)` instance. Because of a stupid decision to make `Monad` a subclass of `Applicative`, we can't do this in one statement, but have to go through `Functor` and `Applicative`, but it's not hard:

```
instance (MonadTransComposeable t1, MonadTransComposeable t2, Monad m) => Functor (X t1 t2 m) where
  fmap h (X ttm) =
    case transformedInstance2 :: MonadInstance (t1 (t2 m)) of
      MonadInstance -> X (fmap h ttm)

instance (MonadTransComposeable t1, MonadTransComposeable t2, Monad m) => Applicative (X t1 t2 m) where
  pure a =
    case transformedInstance2 :: MonadInstance (t1 (t2 m)) of
      MonadInstance -> X (pure a)
  (X ttf) <*> (X tta) =
    case transformedInstance2 :: MonadInstance (t1 (t2 m)) of
      MonadInstance -> X (ttf <*> tta)
```

and, finally

```
instance (MonadTransComposeable t1, MonadTransComposeable t2, Monad m) => Monad (X t1 t2 m) where
  X tta >>= f =
    case transformedInstance2 :: MonadInstance (t1 (t2 m)) of
      MonadInstance -> X (tta >>= \a -> case f a of X ttb -> ttb)
```

Comment: When you say not every transformed monad is a monad, do you mean even for meaningful monad transformer or simply that the signature of monad trans does not guarantee the result to be a monad (because that is obvious, but there often are additional laws to everything so that alone would not be a real problem). Why would something be called monad transformer if it produces bogus results when applied to monads :)

Comment: I mean that "the signature of monad trans does not guarantee the result to be a monad".

Comment: One would need a bunch of extensions to make it work. `GADTs`, `ScopedTypeVariables`, `KindSignatures` and `InstanceSigs`, to be exact.

Comment: That is not surprising at all that `(* -> *) -> * -> *` does not necessarily produce a monad, in that sense not even every `Monad` is `Functor`... just a bogus `Monad` not abiding the laws can just as well violate `Functor` laws...

Answer (score 1):

There is a well known theory which says that monads are not generally composable. That is, given any two arbitrary monads, `t`, and `u` there is no guarantee that `t` ○ `u` is a monad, where (`t` ○ `u`) `a` = `t (u a)`. This seems to be the ultimate reason why this precomposition is not available.

The rational is simple. First, notice that any monad can be written as a transform of the identity monad.  Then, any two monads can be translated to the form of `X`. This corresponds to their composition, which isn't generally allowed, so we know that `X` shouldn't generally be allowed.

Let `Id` be the identity monad,

```
newtype Id a = Id a
```

and let composition be given by:

```
newtype t ○ u a = Comp (t (u a))
```

Also let, for any monad `t`, the composition with `Id` is equal to `t`.

```
t ○ Id ~ t ~ Id ○ t
```

Then, we investigate the case of `X t u m a` wherein `t` `u` are compositions with `Id`. The type and construction are given by

```
X (t ○) (Id ○ (u ○)) (Id ○ m) a 
  = X ((t ○) (Id ○ (u ○ (Id ○ m)) a)
```

And the RHS constructor is equivalent to

```
  ~ X ((t ○) (u ○ m) a)
```

Which has the type

```
X (t ○) (u ○) m a
```

And so the partial application `X (t ○) (u ○)` corresponds to the composition of any two monads, which isn't allowed.

All this isn't to say that we can't compose monads, but rather an explanation of why we need methods such as `transform` or `MonadTransComposable` from Benjamin Hodgson and MigMit, respectively.

I've made this a community wiki, as I expect the above, fast-and-loose proof can be greatly improved by people who actually know what they're doing.